# Adding Parameter Name to Plot Labels

Tags: plotting, labeling

How can I make the curve labels in [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) to show the parameter's name in addition to its number?

(`MSC=100` instead of just `100` in the following graph)

```
gamma4 = .4; gamma3 = .284; gamma2 = .265; gamma1 = .484; z3 = 10000; \
z2 = 32000; z1 = 75000; zbar4 = 4800; zbar3 = 20050; zbar2 = 46200;
zbar1 = 138100; h4 = .301; h3 = .404; h2 = .25;
h1 = .045; p1 = 3.89; p2 = 4.92; p3 = 5.22;
p4 = 5.39;

g1 = 0;  g2 = 0.44;  g3 = 0.88;  g4 = 1.76;


Cost2 = (g2 + 
      MSC (g1 p1 h1 + g2 p2 (h2 - 1) + g3 p3 h3 + 
         g4 p4 h4)) h2 (zbar2 - 
      z2) - (MSC (g1 p1 h1 + g2  p2 (h2 + (1 - τ2)/τ2) + 
        g3 p3 h3 + g4 p4 h4)) h2 zbar2 gamma2 (τ2/(1 - τ2));

Show[Plot[
  Evaluate@Table[Cost2, {MSC, {0,  0.06, 1, 2, 100}}], {τ2, 0, 
   1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.15}, {0, 11000}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, 
  PlotLabels -> Placed[ Table[MSC, {MSC, {0, "" , 1, 2, 100}}], Top]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use StringForm. Note that you may have to add some more padding to see all the labels.

```
Show[Plot[
  Evaluate@Table[Cost2, {MSC, {0, 0.06, 1, 2, 100}}], {\[Tau]2, 0, 1},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 0.15}, {0, 11000}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, 
  PlotLabels -> 
   Placed[Table[
     StringForm["MSC =  ``.", MSC], {MSC, {0, "", 1, 2, 100}}], Top]]]
```